# Implicit casting acting strange

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I have a question about implicit casting for the following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


float max(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
        return a;
    else return b;

}

int main() {
    double a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << max(a, b)<<endl;
    cout << a;


    return 0;
}
```

Now Supposing that `a = 30.5 & b = 26.4`.

The anticipated result is `30` however on one computer(MinGW & VS 2005) I get `30.5`.

Does anyone have an interpretation for this ? It makes no sense to me.

**Edit 1 :**
[image: Implicit conversion acting strangely]

on third line output is 30.5 instead of the anticipated 30

**Solution**
std::max() is shadowing it, but why it shadows it on one computer and it doesn't on another I didn't investigate in that.

So try to avoid naming your functions or classes with names reserved for the standard library.

Comment: I don't believe you got `30.5` as the return value of `max`.

Comment: Hmm seems like maybe a setting with VS 2005.  Is the the other computer you are using VS 2008 or greater?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I will upload a pic

Comment: @AgnosticDev I tried two compilers so it's not about vs 2005

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is whats resulting in the weird output:

```
using namespace std;
```

When calling `max()` you may be calling `std::max()` which may be included in `<iostream>` with no guarantees. Try this:

```
cout << ::max(a, b)<<endl; //forces global scope
```

Should print out `30`.

Comment: std::max() is included in algorithm header and I don't include it

Comment: There are no guarantees that it _isn't included_ in `<iostream>` though. Nothing prevents `<iostream>` from including the file.

Comment: if it's included in iostream, the compiler won't complain about missing function definition when I remove max definition

Comment: I will upload picture to help u get my point, as I feel u don;t

Comment: If you don't believe this answer, try renaming your function "mymax"  -- the behavior you describe will magically go away.

Comment: @ShadyAtef, You said when you remove your definition. Your picture shows yours being there.

Comment: I removed the function entirely and according to your answer & comments it will use std::max(), but it complains about not finding function called max. Not about believing ..

Comment: @chris this is old one, I will upload the new one

Comment: @awesomeyi i wanted to test your answer because it seems so logically for me, but unfortunately I don't have an access to the computer that the problem rose on :)
Thanks